# Select part of a cv::Mat based on non-zero pixels of another Mat?

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I am trying to update part of a Mat based on another Mat. For example, I want to select a part of `img` that is not zero in `mask` and add a constant value to it. When I try this:

```c
Mat mask = imread("some grayscale image with a white area in a black background", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
Mat img = Mat::zeros(mask.rows, mask.cols, CV_8UC1);
Mat bnry, locations;
threshold(mask, bnry, 100, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
findNonZero(bnry, locations);
img(locations) += 5;
```

I get this error:

> Error: Assertion failed ((int)ranges.size() == d)

`img` and `mask` have the same size.

How can I select an area of an image based on another image (mask)?

Comment: in `imread` you have to use flag `cv.:IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` or `cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED` if you want to use a grayscale image as being 1-channel in openCV.

Comment: OK, I added that to imread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of the OpenCV functions will support mask in default, in other word you don't need to find non zero values and based on that doing sum operation, you just need to use `cv::add` function that in default support using mask as an argument,

```
cv::add(img,10,img,mask);  // 10 is an arbitrary constant value
```

And about your code

```
img(locations) += 5;
```

As far as I know we don't have any like this overloaded `operator+` in OpenCV to use.